# Где лучше писать код Java?

Tags: java

В NotePad++ или SublimeText 3? Или вообще ни то и ни другое?

Comment: intellij idea community

Comment: код лучше писать в компании, которая хорошо платит, предоставляет хороший соц.пакет и интересные проекты. это мое субъективное мнение, а вы можете и в нотпаде, дело такое...

Answer (score 4):

В чём вам удобно, в том и пишите.